# as for the theorem to construct R from Q

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I am reading Rudin's principle of mathematics analysis and I am confused about the  theorem 1.19 in chapter 1. How can he construct R from Q. I don't know what are he doing,  how can he construct the irrational number? I haven't seen it. Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: I don't have Rudin's book, but I know two ways to construct $\mathbb R$ from $\mathbb Q$: 1) Dedekind's cuts, 2) sequences.

Comment: It is 2) sequences. He just formaly "adds" the limit of every Cauchy sequence.

Comment: but what does the dedekind's cuts means? I read from the books that it regard the real number as a set, I feel confused about it

Comment: Research the concept of completeness in topology and analysis. The idea is that in complete spaces like the real numbers, all Cauchy sequences coverage, while in incomplete spaces like the rational numbers, there are Cauchy sequences that don't converge.

Comment: but he use the cuts to construct the R instead of the sequences

Comment: That is a similar concept, take the set of all rational numbers smaller than $2$ then the supremum of the set would be $2$. So we can think of every rational number as the set of all rational numbers smaller than it. But we can also define such sets for an arbitrary number, so that is exactly what rudin does. Every set defines a number which is the supremum of the set. And the set of all numbers generated in such a way is $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Rudin's Theorem 1.19 states the existence of a field containing the rational numbers, and then tells you he is calling it the field of real numbers. But he does not go into any details there. Instead, he states that if you are interested, look at the 'bit tedious' proof found in the Appendix.

It turn out that NO HARM IS DONE - one can take a [synthetic approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Synthetic_approach) in describing the real numbers. Not only do we have the existence of these numbers, we also have uniqueness - only one such ordered number field exists (up to an isomorphism) satisfying the lub property.

So you can take it on faith - by studying and understanding the synthetic axioms, you are not 'missing anything', in the sense that there are no properties of the real numbers which you do not know about.

To develop this ever so slightly, notice that in Proposition 1.18 you are told that from the axioms, $0 < 1$. Going further, you could show that our field contains something that acts and feels just like the set of integers. Continuing, since you have multiplicative inverses in a field, you 'must have' the rational numbers. And, if you have considerable amount of time on your hands, you can prove that it can only be 'completed' in one way - $\mathbb{R}$.

If you need a way to get a visual of a real number, think about infinite decimal expansions and look at [Wikipedia 0.999999999999...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...). The article also explains how Dedekind cuts forces you to accept that $.9999999999... = 1$.

[image]